# OCR Unexpected lndent

Tags: python, ocr

I need help with my NEA code for OCR. I am experiencing a "Unexpected indent" error code and need some suggestions on why I could be receiving this error

```
def create_account(username,password):
    with open("Users.csv", "a", newline="") as csvfile:
        appender=csv.writer(csvfile)
        appender.writerow([username,password])
```

---

```
import csv
###MENU######MENU######MENU######MENU######MENU######MENU######MENU###
def display_song(artist, song):
    print(artist) #Print Name Of Song Artist
    words= song.split() #Splits the words of the song
    for current_word in words: #
        no_of_letters = len(current_word) # Counts the amount of letters in the song name
        print(current_word[0]+"_"*(no_of_letters-1)+" ",end="")

def menu(options):
    no_of_options = len(options)
    print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\
n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nn===================================================")
    print("¦ Please choose from one of the following options ¦")
    print("===================================================")
    for each_option in range (no_of_options):
        print("¦"+str(each_option+1)+") "+options[each_option])
    print("===================================================")
    user_input=input("¦  Please Enter an option  ¦> ")
    try:
        option_converted_to_integer = int(user_input)
        if option_converted_to_integer > 0 and option_converted_to_integer <= no_of_options:
            return(option_converted_to_integer)
        else:
            raise
    except:
        print(str(user_input) + " is not a valid option, please try again.")
        return menu(options)

    with open ("Users.csv") as csvfile:
            reader=csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=",")
            for row in reader:import csv
import random
###MENU######MENU######MENU######MENU######MENU######MENU######MENU###
def display_song(artist, song):
    print(artist) #Print Name Of Song Artist
    words= song.split() #Splits the words of the song
    for current_word in words: #
        no_of_letters = len(current_word) # Counts the amount of letters in the song name
        print(current_word[0]+"_"*(no_of_letters-1)+" ",end="")

def menu(options):
    no_of_options = len(options)
    print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\
n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n===================================================")
    print("¦ Please choose from one of the following options ¦")
    print("===================================================")
    for each_option in range (no_of_options):
        print("¦"+str(each_option+1)+") "+options[each_option])
    print("===================================================")
    user_input=input("¦  Please Enter an option  ¦> ")
    try:
        option_converted_to_integer = int(user_input)
        if option_converted_to_integer > 0 and option_converted_to_integer <= no_of_options:
            return(option_converted_to_integer)
        else:
                song_list.append(row[0])
                full_song_list.append(row[0])
                artist_list.append(row[0])

def create_account(username,password):
    with open("Users.csv", "a", newline="") as csvfile:
        appender=csv.writer(csvfile)
        appender.writerow([username,password])
###SIGN UP, LOG IN, QUITTING######SIGN UP, LOG IN, QUITTING######SIGN UP, LOG IN, QUITTING######SIGN UP, LOG IN, QUITTING######SIGN UP, LOG IN, QUITTING######SIGN UP, LOG IN, QUITTING######SIGN UP, LOG IN, QUITTING###
print('\n'*69)
menu_options=["Log In","Create an Account","Quit the program"]
selected_options = menu(menu_options)
while selected_options!=len(menu_options):
        def game():
                    song_list=[]
                    global songlist
                    full_song_list=[]
                    global full_song_list
                    artist_list=[]
                    global artist_list
                    point=0
                    global points
                    successful_guesses=0
                    with open ("song names.csv") as csvfile:
                        reader=csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=",")
                        for row in reader:
                            song_list.append(row[0])
                            full_song_list.append(row[0])
                            artist_list.append(row[0])
                            lives=1
                            while True:
                                song_number=random.randint(0,20)
                                song=song_list[song_number]
                                song_to_guess=full_song_list[song_number]
                                #print("DEBUG: ",song_to_guess,"\n")
                                print(song)
                                print(artist_list[song_number])
                                guess=input("Please guess the artist:\n")
                                song=song.lower()
                                if guess==song_to_guess:
                                    if lives==2:
                                        print("\nCorrect!\n")
                                        while True:
                                            if user_option==1:
                                                log_in()
                                                while True:
                                                    user_option=menu(["Start Game","Exit"])
                                                    print(user_option)
                                                    if user_option==1:
                                                        shown_username=import csv
import random
###MENU######MENU######MENU######MENU######MENU######MENU######MENU######MENU######MENU######MENU######MENU######MENU######MENU######MENU###
def display_song(artist, song):
    print(artist) #Print Name Of Song Artist
    words= song.split() #Splits the words of the song
    for current_word in words: #
        no_of_letters = len(current_word) # Counts the amount of letters in the song name
        print(current_word[0]+"_"*(no_of_letters-1)+" ",end="")

def menu(options):
    no_of_options = len(options)
    print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\
n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n===================================================")
    print("¦ Please choose from one of the following options ¦")
    print("===================================================")
    for each_option in range (no_of_options):
        print("¦"+str(each_option+1)+") "+options[each_option])
    print("===================================================")
    user_input=input("¦  Please Enter an option  ¦> ")
    try:
        option_converted_to_integer = int(user_input)
        if option_converted_to_integer > 0 and option_converted_to_integer <= no_of_options:
            return(option_converted_to_integer)
        else:
            raise
    except:
        print(str(user_input) + " is not a valid option, please try again.")
        return menu(options)

    with open ("Users.csv") as csvfile:
            reader=csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=",")
            for row in reader:import csv
import random
###MENU######MENU######MENU######MENU######MENU######MENU######MENU######MENU######MENU######MENU######MENU######MENU######MENU######MENU###
def display_song(artist, song):
    print(artist) #Print Name Of Song Artist
    words= song.split() #Splits the words of the song
    for current_word in words: #
        no_of_letters = len(current_word) # Counts the amount of letters in the song name
        print(current_word[0]+"_"*(no_of_letters-1)+" ",end="")

def menu(options):
    no_of_options = len(options)
    print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\
n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n===================================================")
    print("¦ Please choose from one of the following options ¦")
    print("===================================================")
    for each_option in range (no_of_options):
        print("¦"+str(each_option+1)+") "+options[each_option])
    print("===================================================")
    user_input=input("¦  Please Enter an option  ¦> ")
    try:
        option_converted_to_integer = int(user_input)
        if option_converted_to_integer > 0 and option_converted_to_integer <= no_of_options:
            return(option_converted_to_integer)
        else:
                song_list.append(row[0])
                full_song_list.append(row[0])
                artist_list.append(row[0])

def create_account (username,password):
   with open("Users.csv", "a", newline="") as csvfile:
        appender=csv.writer(csvfile)
        appender.writerow([username,password])
###SIGN UP, LOG IN, QUITTING######SIGN UP, LOG IN, QUITTING######SIGN UP, LOG IN, QUITTING######SIGN UP, LOG IN, QUITTING######SIGN UP, LOG IN, QUITTING######SIGN UP, LOG IN, QUITTING######SIGN UP, LOG IN, QUITTING###
print('\n'*69)
menu_options=["Log In","Create an Account","Quit the program"]
selected_options = menu(menu_options)
while selected_options!=len(menu_options):
        def game():
                    song_list=[]
                    global songlist
                    full_song_list=[]
                    global full_song_list
                    artist_list=[]
                    global artist_list
                    point=0
                    global points
                    successful_guesses=0
                    with open ("song names.csv") as csvfile:
                        reader=csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=",")
                        for row in reader:
                            song_list.append(row[0])
                            full_song_list.append(row[0])
                            artist_list.append(row[0])
                            lives=1
                            while True:
                                song_number=random.randint(0,20)
                                song=song_list[song_number]
                                song_to_guess=full_song_list[song_number]
                                #print("DEBUG: ",song_to_guess,"\n")
                                print(song)
                                print(artist_list[song_number])
                                guess=input("Please guess the artist:\n")
                                song=song.lower()
                                if guess==song_to_guess:"guest"
                                                        pass
                                                    elif user_option==2:
                                                        game()
                                                        if user_option==2:
                                                            entered_name=input("What is your name?\n")
                                                            if selected_options==2:
                                                                pass

###LOG IN######LOG IN######LOG IN######LOG IN######LOG IN######LOG IN######LOG IN######LOG IN######LOG IN######LOG IN######LOG IN######LOG IN######LOG IN######LOG IN######LOG IN######LOG IN######LOG IN######LOG IN###
        if selected_options==1:
            print('\n'*68)
            input('Enter your username >')
            input('Enter your password >')
            pass
            menu_options=["Start Game","Quit the program"]
            selected_options = menu(menu_options)
            if selected_options==1:
                def game():
                    song_list=[]
                    global songlist
                    full_song_list=[]
                    global full_song_list
                    artist_list=[]
                    global artist_list
                    point=0
                    global points
                    successful_guesses=0
                    with open ("song names.csv") as csvfile:
                        reader=csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=",")
                        for row in reader:
                            song_list.append(row[0])
                            full_song_list.append(row[0])
                            artist_list.append(row[0])
                            lives=1
                            while True:
                                song_number=random.randint(0,20)
                                song=song_list[song_number]
                                song_to_guess=full_song_list[song_number]
                                #print("DEBUG: ",song_to_guess,"\n")
                                print(song)
                                print(artist_list[song_number])
                                guess=input("Please guess the artist:\n")
                                song=song.lower()
                                if guess==song_to_guess:
                                    if lives==2:
                                        print("\nCorrect!\n")
                                        while True:
                                            if user_option==1:
                                                log_in()
                                                while True:
                                                    user_option=menu(["Start Game","Exit"])
                                                    print(user_option)
                                                    if user_option==1:
                                                        shown_username="guest"
                                                        pass
                                                    elif user_option==2:
                                                        game()
                                                        if user_option==2:
                                                            entered_name=input("What is your name?\n")
                                                            if selected_options==2:
                                                                pass

###CREATING AN ACCOUNT######CREATING AN ACCOUNT######CREATING AN ACCOUNT######CREATING AN ACCOUNT######CREATING AN ACCOUNT######CREATING AN ACCOUNT######CREATING AN ACCOUNT######CREATING AN ACCOUNT######CREATING AN ACCOUNT###
        if selected_options==2:
            print('\n'*68)
            create_account(input("Enter your desired username >"), input("Enter your passsword >"))
            pass
        menu_options=["Start Game","Quit the program"]
        selected_options = menu(menu_options)
        if selected_options==1:
            def game():
                song_list=[]
                global songlist
                full_song_list=[]
                global full_song_list
                artist_list=[]
                global artist_list
                point=0
                global points
                successful_guesses=0
                with open ("song names.csv") as csvfile:
                    reader=csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=",")
                    for row in reader:
                        song_list.append(row[0])
                        full_song_list.append(row[0])
                        artist_list.append(row[0])
                        lives=1
                        while True:
                            song_number=random.randint(0,20)
                            song=song_list[song_number]
                            song_to_guess=full_song_list[song_number]
                            #print("DEBUG: ",song_to_guess,"\n")
                            print(song)
                            print(artist_list[song_number])
                            guess=input("Please guess the artist:\n")
                            song=song.lower()
                            if guess==song_to_guess:
                                if lives==2:
                                    print("\nCorrect!\n")
                                    while True:
                                        if user_option==1:
                                            log_in()
                                            while True:
                                                user_option=menu(["Start Game","Exit"])
                                                print(user_option)
                                                if user_option==1:
                                                    shown_username="guest"
                                                    pass
                                                elif user_option==2:
                                                    game()
                                                    if user_option==2:
                                                        entered_name=input("What is your name?\n")
                                                        if selected_options==2:
                                                            pass
###QUITTING THE GAME######QUITTING THE GAME######QUITTING THE GAME######QUITTING THE GAME######QUITTING THE GAME######QUITTING THE GAME######QUITTING THE GAME######QUITTING THE GAME######QUITTING THE GAME######QUITTING THE GAME###

if selected_options==3:
                    pass
##STARTING THE GAME###

#Song List
def game():
    global song_list
    song_list=[]
    global full_song_list
    full_song_list=[]
    global artist_list
    artist_list=[]

    points=0

    global points
    successfuI_guesses=0
    global successful_guesses

    with open ("songs.csv") as csvfile:
            reader=csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=",")
            for row in reader:
                song_list.append(row[0])
                full_song_list.append(row[0])
                artist_list.append(row[0])

            lives=1

            while True:
                song_number=random.randint(0,20)
                song=song_list[song_number]
                song_to_guess=full_song_list[song_number]
                #print("DEBUG: ",song_to_guess,"\n")
                print(song)
                print(artist_list[song_number])
                guess=input("Please guess the artist:\n")
                song=song.lower()
                guess=guess.lower()

                if guess==song_to_guess:
                    if lives==2:
                        print("\nCorrect!\n")
                        points+=3
                        successful_guesses+=1
                    elif lives==1:
                        print("\nCorrect!\n")
                        points=+1
                        successful_guesses=+1



def SignUp():
    userfile = open("Users.csv", "a")
    sUser = input("\nChoose a username: ")
    sPass = input("Choose a password: ")
    sQues = int(input("""
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Security Questions:
1. What is/was your first pet's name?
2. Which town were you born in?
3. What is your mother's maiden name?
4. At what age did you buy your first car?
5. How many seasons of Spongebob have you watched?
6. What secondary school did you go to?
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Choose a Security Question (1-6): """))
    s1 = ("\nWhat is/was your first pet's name?")
    s2 = ("\nWhich town were you born in?")
    s3 = ("\nWhat is your mother's maiden name?")
    s4 = ("\nAt what age did you buy your first car?")
    s5 = ("\nHow many seasons of Spongebob have you watched?")
    s6 = ("\nWhat secondary school did you go to?")
    answered = False
    while answered == False:
        if sQues == 1:
            print(s1)
            sAns = input("Answer: ")
        if sQues == 4:
            print(s4)
            sAns = input("Answer: ")
            answered = True
        if sQues == 5:
            print(s5)
            sAns = input("Answer: ")
            answered = True
        if sQues == 6:
            print(s6)
            sAns = input("Answer: ")
            answered = True
    WriteLine = sUser + "," + sPass + "," + sAns + "\n"
    userfile.write(WriteLine)
    userfile.close()
    print("\nAccount Created!")
    Menu()
```

Comment: could you please post the whole code?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the indentation of the code you have posted.  The interpreter indicates what line the indentation error is on. Look at that more closely, and post the code that includes the point of the error if you still can't see the problem.

Comment: run the code you will see the error

Answer (score 0):

For the `try` in line 52 (function `menu`), you didn't write an `except` and `else`. That's why you are getting the `IndentationError`.

The following code will make the `IndentationError` go away, syntax wise.

```
    def menu(options):
        no_of_options = len(options)
        print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n===================================================")
        print("¦ Please choose from one of the following options ¦")
        print("===================================================")
        for each_option in range (no_of_options):
            print("¦"+str(each_option+1)+") "+options[each_option])
        print("===================================================")
        user_input=input("¦  Please Enter an option  ¦> ")
        try:
            option_converted_to_integer = int(user_input)
            if option_converted_to_integer > 0 and option_converted_to_integer <= no_of_options:
                return(option_converted_to_integer)
            else:
                song_list.append(row[0])
                full_song_list.append(row[0])
                artist_list.append(row[0])
        except:
            pass
        else:
            pass
```

And you have defined `display_song` and `menu` twice.